# How should I declare my namespace for angularJS ui-router so it's valid in html and VS 2013?

Tags: asp.net, html, angularjs, visual-studio

In my index.html I have defined the following:

```
<html class="dark"
      ng-app="app"
      ng-controller="appController"
      id="ng-app"
      xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"
      ng-app="optionalModuleName">
```

In my code I have:

```
 <a ui-sref="home.content({ content: 'overview' })"
    ui-sref-active="current">
```

From what I understand the `xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org` is required by some versions of IE
to identify the different namespaces.

Now I am also using ui-router. So how should I declare the namespace?

I assume `xmlns:ui`  but what should I put after that ?

Also in VS2013 it's coming up as invalid. Is there a way I can tell VS2013 to ignore ui- that it sees in HTML ?

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear in the first place - you are naming your index site `index.html`. This confused me a little since namespaces are only valid, when used in `xml` documents. For `html` it would be the `xml` application `xhtml`. If you do not know the difference, please read it up on the web. There are many good tutorials and articles explaining the differences between `html`and `xhtml`.

Back to your question: As far as I can see from their source code, the ui router is developed in valid angularjs, and the usage is like the usage of angular directives, so you should be fine only including the angularjs namespace to your root element.
Please also read the following document for further introductions on how to make angularjs compatible with Internet Explorer: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

As for your second question, I don't know if you can setup VS2013 to ignore certain attributes, but since html5 you are able to add `data-` before them to make them valid (x)html.
As described in here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
and here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

So for example:

```
<a data-ui-sref="home.content({ content: 'overview' })"
    data-ui-sref-active="current">
```